# Jupyter Notebook reports syntax error on code that isn't present

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Has anybody ever seen a Jupyter notebook give an error referring to code that is not actually present in the notebook?

Notice that in the image below, the Syntax error refers to line 6 and the text `return amounts: {result}")`

This code does not appear in this block (or any other block in the notebook).  Nor does the string `s: {result}")` which is the substring that appears in the error, but not in line  6.

[image]

Comment: Something something reset the kernel…?

Comment: In that interface, do cells need to be saved before running them?

Comment: You may have encountered what sometimes is called the 'hidden state' of a Jupyter `.ipynb` file. As the comments by decreze and John Gordon suggest, save and restart the kernel regularly to avoid that issue creeping in.

Answer (score 0):

its because jupyter notebook are basically json so this type of errors you need to reset the metadata of the cell

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).